# Switch between Flex Tabbed ViewNavigators

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blackberry-playbook

I am working on a Flex `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication` with three tabs (ViewNavigator elements). I would like to switch from one ViewNavigator to another based upon a user action (via ActionScript code).

I know that switching between Views uses `pushView` and `popView`, but I'm working with ViewNavigators, and my searching revealed nothing useful.

I'm trying to switch from Tab2 to Tab1 when an event occurs. In this case, Tab2 contains a list, and when the user makes a selection, I want to jump back to Tab1.

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                  creationComplete="onAppReady(event)">
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab1" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabOneView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab2" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabTwoView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab3" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabThreeView"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is strangely undocumented.  I have not tried this myself, but from searching online, [this is what I found](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS77c1dbb1bd80d383527e1a6412a8a5d909a-8000.html#WSe11993ea1bd776e577ad4b2d12a42c5858a-7ffe) which corroborates with what the rest of the network does.

What you need to do is bubble an event to the `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication` and from there change the `selectedIndex` property to whichever tab you need to change to.  For example:

```
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                                  creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                this.addEventListener('someEvent', someHandler);
            }

            private function someHandler(e:Event):void
            {
                this.selectedIndex = 0; // or whatever index you want. 
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab1" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabOneView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab2" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabTwoView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator label="Tab3" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.TabThreeView"/>
</s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication>
```

You just need to dispatch a bubbling event from within your children.  You could event create a custom event that holds data about which tab to switch to.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following line of ActionScript to switch from one `ViewNavigator` to another based on a user action:

```
TabbedViewNavigator(navigator.parentNavigator).selectedIndex = 1;
```

It worked like a charm and seems simpler than bubbling events.