# Programmatically switch between flex ViewNavigators

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, view, air, tabnavigator

I have a Flex TabbedViewNavigatorApplication

With two custom navigators:

```
<s:navigators>
    <homepagenavigator:HomePageNavigatorView label="Home" id="homePageNavigator" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <categorylistpagenavigator:CategoryListPageNavigatorView label="List of Categories" id="categoryListPageNavigatorView" width="100%" height="100%" />
</s:navigators>
```

Now I want to programmatically, based on some events inside my app to switch between navigators.

The only question on StackOverflow I found is this [Switch between Flex Tabbed ViewNavigators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118344/switch-between-flex-tabbed-viewnavigators)

but the solution is only applicable if you are working inside your Main.mxml, 
which is either to use `navigator.selectedIndex = 1;` (or in my case `tabbedNavigator.selectedIndex = 1;`) or to use `TabbedViewNavigator(navigator.parentNavigator).selectedIndex = 1;`

but I have no idea how to access navigator inside my app, not in Main.mxml

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use an Event, create a NavigationEvent that extends from event like this:

```
  public class NavigationEvent extends Event
{
    public static const GO_TO_DESTINATION:String = "goToDestination";

    private var _destIndex:Number;
    private var _param:Object;

    public function NavigationEvent(type:String, destIndex:Number)
    {
        super(type, true);
        this._destIndex = destIndex;
    }
```

And then add the event listener to the component from where you want to change the tab.

```
COMPONENENT.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.GO_TO_DESTINATION, handleResult);
```

And then in the handleResult method switch the view.

```
 private function goto(event:NavigationEvent):void{
            vs.selectedIndex = event.destIndex;
        }
```